# Unknown Method – when using set/get method on active record model property Yii2

Tags: php, oop, yii

Lets say I have a table 'account' with below structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Index',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UserID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
)
```

I have created a model 'Account' for that using gii.

When I try create new account, I want `user_id` to be assigned from session

So, In the controller, I tried like below.

```
$model = new Account();
$model->**setUser_Id**(Yii::$app->user->getID());

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
```

But, I don't write any `setUser_Id` method in Account model, since I assumed when I call set methods, it will automatically assign the property of ActiveRecord.

But its throwing error. But it works fine when I try

```
$model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->getID();
```

As per documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/, 
Note that the get/set functions can be called directly as functions (but requiring the usual function-call parentheses):

```
$x = $model->fullname;
$x = $model->getFullname();        // same thing

$model->active = 1;
$model->setActive(1);              // same thing
```

Can you experts throw some light on this please?

Comment: Actually I was expecting that to be work as two way, i.e When I call setUserId on model , I expected Yii to set the model property user_id itself from AciveRecord setter.

because in my model Account class, user_id property is not explicitly defined. but still i am able to use it like $model->user_id , that means, it triggers set/get method when i try to access the property which is not explicitly defined in class.

I guess, the default getter/setter method takes the property name and calls getAttribute/setAttribute within that.. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

[edit] read the question a bit better and did few clarifications to make the answer more comprehensive.

The exception is actually expected.

The way the whole virtual attributes functionality has been implemented in Yii shows that when calling `$model->attribute` the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()` search for the attribute name in the table columns, and if not, search for the getter or setter, respectively, that you might have implemented. (That's very approximate but should give you the idea, more information can be seen by looking at the code: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L237)

This means that the virtual attributes work only one way natively. Otherwise you can always access them via a direct method call using `$model->getAttribute('my_attribute');` and `$model->setAttribute('my_attribute', $value);`

The example you're taking from the link you posted is out of context (apart having been written for Yii 1): in there you get the getter/setter implemented manually and later called in both ways.

The only case where names might not be coherent with what you have in the database is when the table name contains underscores, in which case they'll be removed: e.g. `people_manager` becomes `PeopleManager` as class name for the model.

It's not anyway clear what you're trying to achieve, this might help us give you a better direction on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: I already tried setUserID() and setuserID() it and it was not working.

Calling unknown method: app\modules\manage\models\Account::setUserId()

Comment: updated my answer, made it more clear hopefully. As I state at the end, it would be good to know what you're trying to achieve in order to help you take the right implementation decision.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Actually I was expecting that to be work as two way, i.e When I call setUserId on model , I expected Yii to set the model property user_id itself from AciveRecord setter.

because in my model Account class, user_id property is not explicitly defined. but still i am able to use it like $model->user_id , that means, it triggers set/get method when i try to access the property which is not explicitly defined in class.

I guess, the default getter/setter method takes the property name and calls getAttribute/setAttribute within that.. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct: the ability to get/set `$model->user_id` without it being defined explicitly anywhere in code, is because of `__get()` and `__set()` being implemented in the `BaseActiveRecord` Class. In Yii2  the `__get()` and `__set()` magic method never calls `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` respectively. They do their own work resulting in getting/setting the attribute if found 1) as a table column, 2) if there is the getter/setter defined for the attribute 3) other (see code). Hope this clears things up.

Comment: My intended question is : Is this two way/ One way ?

OneWay: we can only access undefined property ( given that its an column name), not the undefined method on the column name

TwoWay: we can call both undefined property and method given that property is column name and method is set/get<column_name>()

Does my question make sense?

Comment: It is *one way* and you can access `$model->user_id` only if it's in the db OR you have it defined as public property of your model; it is *two ways* and you can access both `$model->user_id` *and* `$model->get/setUser_Id()` if you have the method defined in the model (with certain exceptions/combinations of public property and column in the db).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that it throws an exeception, because you have not written any setter or getter. ActiveRecord in yii implementation uses virtual attributes (implemented via __get()/__set() magic function), which can be accessed like $model->attribute and $model->attribute = $value.
You can not use $model->getAttribute() or $model->setAttribute($value), until you implement them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Actually I was expecting that to be work as two way, i.e When I call setUserId on model , I expected Yii to set the model property user_id itself from AciveRecord setter.

because in my model Account class, user_id property is not explicitly defined. but still i am able to use it like $model->user_id , that means, it triggers set/get method when the property is not explicitly defined in class.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because PHP is case-sensitive about user-defined identifiers. When you use `$model->user_id` then you should call `$model->setUser_id` and not `$model->setUser_Id` or `$model->setUserId`, etc. I mean, only the first letter after set is capital and the rest is as the field name. Let me now if this answer solved your problem.

Comment: I called this as well '$model->setUser_id' but the result is same:

Calling unknown method: modules\manage\models\Account::setUser_id()

Comment: I red Yii docs deeply and finally found that these __set and __get functions are very very internal and you should not use them (I don't know in which version exactly their opinion about this feature is changed) but I found that you can use `$model->__set('user_id', 5);` or `$model->setAttributes(array('user_id'=>5));` and the easy way `$model->user_id = 5;` for setting attribute value and doing the same for getting it. If this helped you, let me know to update the answer.

Comment: If you still want to use `setUser_id` and `getUser_id` methods (I don't know why it's needed) you can override these methods in your model and Yii automatically use them when you use magic `__set` and `__get` magic methods as far as I know.